# mysql returns wrong results with random duplicate values

Tags: mysql

i need to return the **best 5 scores in each category** from a table.so far i have tried query below following an example from this site: [selecting top n records per group](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group)

**query:**

```
select  
 subject_name,substring_index(substring_index
  (group_concat(exams_scores.admission_no order by exams_scores.score desc),',',value),',',-1) as names,
     substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(score order by score desc),',',value),',',-1)
 as orderedscore
 from exams_scores,students,subjects,tinyint_asc 
where tinyint_asc.value >=1 and tinyint_asc.value <=5 and exam_id=2 
  and exams_scores.admission_no=students.admission_no and   students.form_id=1 and 
exams_scores.subject_code=subjects.subject_code group by  exams_scores.subject_code,value;
```

i get the top n as i need b**ut my problem is that its returning duplicates at random which i dont know where they are coming from**

As you can see English and Math have duplicates which should not be there

```
+------------------+-------+--------------+
| subject_name     | names | orderedscore |
+------------------+-------+--------------+
| English          | 1500  | 100          |
| English          | 1500  | 100          |
| English          | 2491  | 100          |
| English          | 1501  | 99           |
| English          | 1111  | 99           |
|Mathematics       | 1004  | 100          |
| Mathematics      | 1004  | 100          |
| Mathematics      | 2722  | 99           |
| Mathematics      | 2734  | 99           |
| Mathematics      | 2712  | 99           |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I have checked table and no duplicates exist

to confirm there are no duplicates in the table:

```
select * from exams_scores 
   having(exam_id=2) and (subject_code=121) and (admission_no=1004);
```

**result :**

```
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
| id   | admission_no | exam_id | subject_code | score |
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
| 4919 | 1004         |       2 |          121 |   100 |
+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

same result for English.

If i run the query like 5 times i sometimes end up with another field having duplicate values.

can anyone tell me why my query is behaving this way..i tried adding distinct inside

```
group_concat(ditinct(exams_scores.admission_no))
```

but that didnt work ??

Comment: Just a side note: You shouldn't use the old comma-separated join syntax. It was the only thing available in the 1980s and early 90s, but then explicit joins (INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN etc.) where introduced to replace the old error-prone syntax. Use these instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping by `exams_scores.subject_code, value`. If you add them to your selected columns (`...as orderedscore, exams_scores.subject_code, value from...`), you should see that all rows are distinct with respect to these two columns you grouped by. Which is the correct semantics of `GROUP BY`.

Edit, to clarify:

1. First, the SQL server removes some rows according to your `WHERE` clause.
2. Afterwards, it groups the remaining rows according to your `GROUP BY` clause.
3. Finally, it selects the colums you specified, either by directly returning a column's value or performing a `GROUP_CONCAT` on some of the columns and returning their accumulated value.

If you select columns not included in the `GROUP BY` clause, the returned results for these columns are arbitrary, since the SQL server reduces all rows equal with respect to the columns specified in the `GROUP BY` clause to one single row - as for the remaining columns, the results are pretty much undefined (hence the "randomness" you're experiencing), because - what should the server choose as a value for this column? It can only pick one randomly from all the reduced rows.

In fact, some SQL servers won't perform such a query and return an SQL error, since the result for those columns would be undefined, which is something you don't want to have in general. With these servers (I believe MSSQL is one of them), you more or less can only have columns in you `SELECT` clause which are part of your `GROUP BY` clause.

Edit 2: Which, finally, means that you have to refine your `GROUP BY` clause to obtain the grouping that you want.